# Cognitive (neuro)science and related mailing lists

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, internet

I am looking for cognitive neuroscience (and related) mailing lists. For some time I have been subscribed to [Visionlist](http://visionscience.com/mailman/listinfo/visionlist) and found it to be a tremendous source of information about conferences, PhD and postdoc opportunities.
Does anybody else know any similar, good sources?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The Visionlist is indeed extremely helpful. It's not quite the same, but I found the mailing lists of the [Organization for Human Brain Mapping (OHBM)](https://www.humanbrainmapping.org) and of the [Cognitive Neuroscience Society (CNS)](https://www.cogneurosociety.org) quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a recently created cognitive science mailing list that is managed by the Cognitive Science Society.

Information here: http://www.cognitivesciencesociety.org/2016/08/10/new-cogsci-mailing-list/

Subscribe here: http://lists.cognitivesciencesociety.org/listinfo.cgi/announcements-cognitivesciencesociety.org